# Natural language processing

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, pandas, nltk

I am new to NLP. I converted my JSON file to CSV with the Jupyter notebook. I am unsure how to proceed in pre-processing my data using techniques such as tokenization and  lemmatization etc. I normalised the data before converting it to a CSV format, so now i have a data frame. Please how do I apply the tokenisation process on the whole dataset and using the `split()` function is giving me an error?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. We need more detail to help you: which task are you doing, text classification? how does your data look like? Please add any other relevant information. You can also find tutorials such as [this one](https://realpython.com/nltk-nlp-python/#getting-started-with-pythons-nltk) for nltk, since you used the nltk tag.

Comment: Thanks for your message, i have edited my question for more clarity

Comment: I don't understand exactly what happens, but it looks like your data is formatted in a strange way. Normally you shouldn't have to split on the `,`, it looks like the conversion didn't work properly. The first thing you need is to be able to extract the text that you're going to process, I'm not sure what's the point of going through this pandas dataframe, I suspect that it only makes things harder. Also I don't know what your data look like so I can't help much.

Comment: I thought using the pandas dataframe will be easier for me to manipulate, i can use any method. I am finding the preprocessing steps very difficult because of the dataset.  Please here is the link to the dataset  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/clinc/oos-eval/master/data/data_full.json

Answer (score 0):

Ok, something like this should work:

```
import json
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

with open('data_full.json','r') as f:
    data0 = f.read()
rawdata = json.loads(data0)

for dataset,instances in rawdata.items():
    for instance in instances:
        sentence = instance[0]
        label = instance[1]
        tokens = word_tokenize(sentence)
        print('in ',dataset,': ', '|'.join(tokens),'; label:', instance[1])
        lemmas = [ lemmatizer.lemmatize(token) for token in tokens ]
        print('          lemmas = ','|'.join(lemmas))
```

Note: you will probably need to install a few resources for nltk, follow the instructions given in the error messages.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will try it out now and get back.